# Getting error while running: RUN yarn global add @vue/cli @quasar-cli from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, vue.js, yarnpkg, quasar

Getting an error with this Dockerfile below, any help would be appreciated?
ERROR:

> *warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-shared-utils > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
>   warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > vue-cli-plugin-apollo > apollo > git-parse > babel-polyfill > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
>   warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > vue-cli-plugin-apollo > apollo > git-parse > babel-polyfill > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
>   error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@quasar-cli: Request \"https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@quasar-cli\" returned a 405".*
>   info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/yarn-error.log".
>   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
>   The command '/bin/sh -c yarn global add @vue/cli @quasar-cli' returned a non-zero code: 1

```
FROM node:12-alpine as dependencies


WORKDIR /app
CMD npx quasar dev
EXPOSE 8083

USER root

**RUN yarn global add @vue/cli @quasar-cli --network-timeout 100000**
ADD package.json .
RUN yarn --network-timeout 100000
COPY . .


# build static assets to be served 
FROM node:12-alpine as builder

RUN yarn global add @vue/cli @quasar-cli
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=dependencies /app /app

ENV PROD 1
ARG PROJECT_ID
ENV PROJECT_ID=${PROJECT_ID}
RUN quasar build



# small final image containing only the static assets
FROM node:12-alpine as server
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /app/dist

RUN yarn global add http-server
WORKDIR /app/dist/spa-mat

ARG PORT=8088
ENV PORT=${PORT}
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD sh -c http-server . -p $PORT -s
```

Comment: In the interim I am using npm in place of yarn and it is working as expected.